# javascript links same number as div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
         ..//
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
         ..//
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
         ..//
    </div>

    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to make the number of `li` the same as the number of `slide` with javascript/jquery

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
var pagination = $('.pagination li a').size();
var slides = $('.slide').size();

$(function(){
 pagination=slides;
});
```

This is my real question, if I have more then one slider, how can i make the number of links inside of the div to be equal to the slides inside the `div class="slider"` not all the slides in the page

In other words if I have the html i typed and i have another structure like this one but with more/less `div class="slide"` how can i make the links in the pagination equal to the number of thos divs

Comment: Will the starting number of `li` ever be larger than the number of `div`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat convoluted approach is as follows:

```
// iterate over each `.slider` element@
$('.slider').each(function(index){
    // look within the current '.slider' for the '.pagination' element
    var menu = $(this).find('.pagination');

    // iterate over each of the '.slide' elements:
    $(this).find('.slide').each(function(i){
        // caching the current DOM node:
        var self = this;

        // setting the 'id', assuming that no id is currently assigned
        self.id = 'slide_' + index + '_' + i;

        // creating the 'li', appending it to the menu (as found, above):
        var li = $('<li />').appendTo(menu),

            // creating the 'a' element:
            a = $('<a />', {
                // setting its text to:
                text : 'slide ' + (i + 1), // omit the '+ 1' if you're
                                           // okay with zero-based counting
                // setting the 'href' to be equal to the slide's 'id' (as set above)
                // this allows clicking on the 'a' element to take you to the slide
                href : '#' + self.id
            }).appendTo(li);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5t2Py/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: thanks man this is what i've been looking for :) but i wasnt quite sure how to write it down

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped; and thank *you* for the accept! =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` on the `div`s, and call `append()` on the `ul` (with class 
`pagination`) to add one `li` for each `div`:

```
$(".pagination").empty();
$('.slide').each(function(_, value){
    $(".pagination").append('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
});
```

It will remove all `li`s and add as much `li`s as there are `div`s.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QSLLv/)

---

This other solution will only work on the difference.

If there are more `div`s than `li`s, it will add the number necessary to match.

On the other hand, if there are more `li`s than `div`s. It will remove the last `li`s until the number is equal.

```
var pagination = $('.pagination li a').size();
var slides = $('.slide').size();

if (slides > pagination) {
    for(var i = pagination; i < slides; i++) {
        $(".pagination").append('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
    }
}
else {
     for(var i = slides; i < pagination; i++) {
        $(".pagination li:last-child").remove();
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fS46R/)

Comment: Note that the ul must be emtpy for this to work. Otherwise you should empty it first: $(".pagination").empty()

Comment: @SebastianG Totally agreed. I'm waiting on some feedback from him as I have a feeling this won't be enough.

Comment: i've edited my question to what i really mend :)

Comment: @user2374907 If you are only worried about the number of `li`s, check again the fiddle, I edited the answer.

Comment: for some reason your else doesnt seem to work cause it adds the li to all the pagination but it doesnt remove it if the links are more then the slides

Comment: Check this updated fiddle of the second solution (if/else). The button will make things clearer I hope: http://jsfiddle.net/fS46R/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you wanna accomplish. There is the code you need:

```
$(function(){
var pagination = $('.pagination li'),
    slides = $('.slider > .slide');
if (slides.size() > pagination.size()){
    var diff = slides.size() - pagination.size();
    for (var numero=1; numero<=diff; numero++){
        $('.pagination li:last').after('<li><a href="#"></a></li>')
    }
}
```

});

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CUXTW/1/

Comment: it both works and not at the same time, the problem right now is this: I have more more then one sliders and each has 'div class slide' and 'ul class pagination' and if i create a new link after the last li it creates it after the last '.pagination li' in the whole page, not in the certain 'div class slider' which increase or decrease the number of slides. Saying this in a more simple way if in my first 'div class slider' i put another 'div class slide' the pagination that will increment with one will be the last one not the one inside the div

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an abstract, customizable solution. I packed it in the form of a jQuery plugin but you can easily tweak / extract functionality from it:

```
(function($) {
    function render(i) {
        return "<li><a href=\"#"+i+"\">"+i+"</a></li>";
    }

    function pager(options) {
        var pagination = $(this).find(options.pagination).first();
        for(var p = 0; p < $(this).find(options.slide).length; p ++) {
            var link = render(p);
            pagination[0].innerHTML += link;
        }
    };

    $.fn.paginate = function(options) {
        render = options.render || render;
        this.each(function(index, slider) {
            pager.call(slider, options);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You can easily use it in this way:

```
$(".slider").paginate({
    slide: ".slide", 
    pagination: ".pagination", 
    render: function(i) {
        return "<a href=\"#"+i+"\">Number "+i+"</a>";
    }
});
```

Note that in this implementation "slide" and "pagination" options are required, and you can pass an optional "render" function which gets called with an argument: the index of the pagination element being rendered. You can easily accomplish what you need from there (a default render fuuction is included anyway).

Working demo (with multiple sliders in page) at: http://jsfiddle.net/xs3fu/2/.

Hope this helps.